# Appending to an existing feature class attribute and batching to the rest of the attributes in the feature QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, telecom

I am trying to figure out how to add (before and after the existing data) to a specific feature class and batch it for the rest of the attributes.

For instance, if I have a set of numbers, "12345678", and I need to add a prefix to this to make it "FIB_AER::123456789". I hope explained it in an understandable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Field Calculator with concat:

```
concat('FIB_AER::', yourfieldnamehere)
```

[image]